# using a variable inside a trigger

Tags: mysql

I am testing out my trigger and it works well all except i can't seem my variables don't seem to work like they should.

For instance

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER lestrigger
    AFTER INSERT ON examinations
   FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE the_last_inserted_id INT ;
    DECLARE the_class_id INT;
    DECLARE the_year_id INT;

    SET the_last_inserted_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    SET the_class_id = (select examination_class_id from examinations where examination_id = 1);
    SET the_year_id = (select examination_class_id from examinations where examination_id = 1);

insert into examination_data (ed_cs_id,ed_examination_id)  select cs_id,@the_last_insert_id from class_students where cs_class_id = 1 AND cs_year_id = 1;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

In this line

```
insert into examination_data (ed_cs_id,ed_examination_id)  select cs_id,the_last_insert_id from class_students where cs_class_id = 1 AND cs_year_id = 1;
```

`the_last_insert_id` is being seen as a column

When i try this,`@the_last_insert_id`,its not seen as a column but its not working either.I have not tried the rest of my variables.

How am i going to define and use this `the_last_inserted_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();` for instance?.

Comment: `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO your_variable_name` or `SET your_variable_name = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`. You use a `select` statement for all your variables except when invoking `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set

```
Select STH into the_last_inserted_id from TBL limit 1;

insert into examination_data (ed_cs_id,ed_examination_id)
select cs_id,the_last_insert_id 
from class_students
where cs_class_id = 1 AND cs_year_id = 1;
```

Edit:
@ - You are using without declaring, just seting

```
Select STH into @new_id from TBL limit 1;
```

and then

```
insert into examination_data (ed_cs_id,ed_examination_id)
select cs_id,@the_last_insert_id
from class_students
where cs_class_id = 1 AND cs_year_id = 1;
```